# How to get linked title(NOT only text) using Youtube API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube

I want to show "the lists of title that have a link" to users when they search videos and when they click the link, it should be play in same div

I followed some tutorials and I made it to show "title and video" in one div.

Like this

```
function tplawesome(e,t){res=e;for(var n=0;n<t.length;n++){res=res.replace(/\{\{(.*?)\}\}/g,function(e,r){return t[n][r]})}return res}

    $(function() {
        $("form").on("submit", function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          // prepare the request
          var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
                part: "snippet",
                type: "video",
                q: $("#media_search").val(),
                maxResults: 5,
                videoDuration: "medium",
                publishedAfter: "2000-01-01T00:00:00Z"

          }); 
          // execute the request
          request.execute(function(response) {
              var results = response.result;
               $("#youtube_results").empty();
              $("#youtube_results").html("");
               $.get("item.html", function(data) {
                $.each(results.items, function(index, item) {
                 $("#youtube_results").append(
                        tplawesome(data, [{"title":item.snippet.title, "videoid":item.id.videoId}]));
                });
               });
              resetVideoHeight();
          });
        });

        $(window).on("resize", resetVideoHeight);
    });

    function resetVideoHeight() {
        $(".video").css("height", $("#youtube_results").width() * 9/16);
    }

    function init() {
        gapi.client.setApiKey("My_key");
        gapi.client.load("youtube", "v3", function() {
            // yt api is ready
        });
    }
```

And Here is my HTML code

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group input-group-md" style="padding-top:37px;padding-bottom:10px;">
            <span>
                <i class="fa fa-language"></i>
            </span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="keywords" autocomplete="off" id="media_search">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <input type="submit" value="search" class="form-control btn btn-default">
                </span>
           </div>
       </div>
 </form>
 <div class="panel panel-default">
     <div class="panel-body" id="youtube_results">
     </div>
 </div>
```

But what I have to do to get titles that have direct link (NOT only text)?

**For example**,

I want to show results like this webpage

http://www.rappad.co/editor

Right side of this web page, "Search or attach media" section shows lists of title and when you click it, it play video immediately.

Answer (score 1):

The search results don't actually contain a URL to the video (just urls to thumbnails). It does, however, return the 'videoId' field. That is the magic key you need to play the video. You can construct the URL simply by concatenating the videoId with this "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v="

See example output below (this is just one entry in the list of results)

```
etag = "\"jOXstHOM20qemPbHbyzf7ztZ7rI/sac7bhRUtt0cHYR4ntn0iH5E54U\"";
    items =     (
                {
            etag = "\"jOXstHOM20qemPbHbyzf7ztZ7rI/o6DPa3ydgPLZK1l-83eAXJG97Xs\"";
            id =             {
                kind = "youtube#video";
                videoId = JeQuelXsUYA;
            };
            kind = "youtube#searchResult";
            snippet =             {
                channelId = "UCjs0c_gIgDg7-3iroN7Qxfw";
                channelTitle = "";
                description = “<long description> ...";
                liveBroadcastContent = none;
                publishedAt = "2015-01-14T21:11:18.000Z";
                thumbnails =                 {
                    default =                     {
                        url = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/JeQuelXsUYA/default.jpg";
                    };
                    high =                     {
                        url = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/JeQuelXsUYA/hqdefault.jpg";
                    };
                    medium =                     {
                        url = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/JeQuelXsUYA/mqdefault.jpg";
                    };
                };
                title = "Monitor Color Test / Monitor-Farbtest (RGB/CMYK) (1080p)";
            };
        },
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! but Where I put this code for test in my code?